# Show(); Function Not Working For Windows Forms C++

Tags: c++, forms, clr

I'm trying to make my login form open up another windows form, however `Show` and `ShowDialog` are not working, I get a error saying " 'Show' is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::MainMenu'.

Not sure why this could be, and Google isn't showing any results here, and could really use some help.

[image]

```
private:
    System::Void loginButton_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        //*Insert SQL Login validation*

        //Once the login has been validated, lets encrypt the client's data and continue to splash page
        this->Hide();
        MainMenu^ mm = gcnew MainMenu();
        mm->Show();

        //mm->ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: The error is correct. A [`MainMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu?view=netframework-4.8) is not a `Form`, so you can't `Show()` it as-is. it is a control that you place onto a `Form`, and then you can `Show()` the `Form`.

Comment: MainMenu however is my 2nd form.. I have already added buttons to it and everything.

Comment: Just changed MainMenu to Form and it "worked" however it's not the right form. No buttons, and it's in light theme (I have the form i made set to dark theme)

Comment: `Form` as-is is just a blank base window class. You need a derived class with controls on it. If your derived Form really is named `MainMenu` then you need to rename it to avoid conflicting with .NET's own [`MainMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu?view=netframework-4.8) class. Something like `MainMenuForm` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, realized my mistake, it needed to be Form^ mm = gcnew MainMenu();